# Python, I can't understand this statement what does that mean

Tags: python

Write a python program to accept 2 "string" numbers for calculation. 
Note : convert string number to an Integer before perform the calculation

Any examples answer?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you. If you don't understand your assignment, ask your instructor for help. If you've tried solving your problem and are having problems, then maybe you can ask here. We'd be happy to assist you, but you need to do some work yourself first.

Comment: Probably you need to convert str to int like this `s = '1234' n=int(s)` and the same with second number

Answer (score 1):

You have to accept input in string, use `raw_input()`,  and you have to parse them in `int`. And perform your calculation

Comment: You have to apply your logic further, not providing code for this @user8537998